# Why can't i show data in print?

Tags: json, swift3

I have this code with Alamofire lib and i'm trying to print data of nome, but the result is just "(lldb)", why?

```
@IBAction func botaoAcesse(_ sender: Any) {

let cpf = self.campoCPF.text
let senha = self.campoSenha.text

let param = ["cpf": cpf, "senha": senha, "method": "app-get-login", "plataforma":"ios"]
var _: HTTPHeaders = ["Content-Type": "application/json"]
let url = "http://easypasse.com.br/gestao/wsLogin.php"

Alamofire.request(url, method:.post, parameters:param,encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
    switch response.result {
    case .success:
        print(response)
        if let JSON = response.result.value as? [String: Any] {
            let registro =  JSON["registro"] as? String
            let usuario = JSON["usuario"] as? String
            let nome = JSON["nome"] as? String
            print(nome!)

        }

    case .failure(let error):
        print(0,"Error")
    }
}
```

}

And the result is

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please (learn to) read the JSON – which is actually a Swift collection type output. Nevermind, in both cases `{}` represents a dictionary.

The value for key `registro` and `usuario` is both dictionary and `registro` is a child of `json` and `usuario` is a child of `registro` and `nome` is a child of `usuario`.

```
if let json = response.result.value as? [String: Any],
   let registro = json["registro"] as? [String: Any],
   let usuario = registro["usuario"] as? [String: Any],
   let nome = usuario["nome"] as? String {
            print(nome)

   }
```

Nevertheless in Swift 4 it's highly recommended to use `Codable`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are mixing types of strings, arrays, and json objects. What if you try something like this?

```
    let nome = response.registro.usuario.nome as? String
```

If you're receiving a JSON response I'd assign all the variables out first before converting the response into a string. JSON is a lot easier to work with when dealing with objects.